# permanent direct download links to microsoft store .appxbundle?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store

I know https://store.rg-adguard.net/ can generate **temporary** links from ms store to download the .appxbundle/.appx files. However, I'd like a more "permanent" solution for my script.

Still lowkey beginner at powershell scripting so bear with me.

Anyone got any ideas?

Code I'm using for downloading files in case you were wondering.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$DownloadURI" -OutFile "$DownloadPath" -TimeoutSec "3600"
```

Comment: Re-read my answer, has updated details about what you're asking for.

Also, check out the powershell code, as it will still answer part of your question as to how to get the temporary download link with Powershell alone.

Answer (score 0):

ATTENTION: I realize my script had some bugs that would cause some downloads not to work... try the 2.0.1 (or newer) version and it should work now.

You won't find a permanent solution, as by the store's own implementation, everything is generated for a temporary session (of up to 10 minutes from the time the downloads are generated). Not to mention that some packages actually have dependencies that need to be downloaded with it.

To be clear, https://store.rg-adguard.net/ wouldn't exist if there were endpoints for downloading the files directly without time limits. Additionally, the availability of ".appxbundle" is largely up to if the dev of the app uploaded said file, which is not always the case... which is why you have to expect either of 4 types (2 bundle types, .msixbundle or .appxbundle; 2 single types, .msix or .appx). It should also be known that you're likely going to see less and less of .appx/.appxbundle, as .msix/.msixbundle are the standards that improves upon and replaces them (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sgern/but-what-about-app-v)

However, to make things easier to script, I made the following at: https://github.com/Andrew-J-Larson/OS-Scripts/blob/main/Windows/Wrapper-Functions/Get-AppxPackage-Function.ps1

Which downloads the package needed, along with dependencies.